# Adobe Connect doesn't allow me to share one of my monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, adobe-connect

Adobe Connect doesn't allow me to share one of my monitors: I have 4 monitors, but when I click on `share my screen` I have only the following options:

[image]

My 4th monitor is missing from the list. `Document` is a window located on the `First Monitor`.

My Adobe Connect version is 9.7.0 and I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate:

[image]

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.